# Line reading in bash

Tags: bash

So I found this example online and I am still a little clueless.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
name=$line
echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < t
```

My file is called list.txt and is in the same folder as my script. What do I have to add/modify to the above to get it to read my list line by line?

Comment: Change `done < t` for `done < list.txt`

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read name
do
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: I get these errors now.

./project.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./project.sh: line 5: `done < list.txt'

Comment: Well it works fine for me.  I'm on a Mac, what about you?  I'm pretty sure the above will work on Linux too.

Comment: @Voldemort What you were given is exactly correct, and shouldn't have a problem on Cygwin, either. I'd suggest making sure you copied it _exactly_ (including the `do`), and that you don't have something funny going on with your file (like DOS line endings on a Cygwin environment configured not to convert).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass your filename to the script as a parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
while read name; do
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < "$file"
```

and invoke it like this:

```
./myscript list.txt
```